# Any solutions on splitting output file?

Tags: etl, talend, talend-mdm

I'm a newbie here in Talend and what I am trying to do is to split different output file, here is an example of the file that I am working on...

[File of Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7cyb.png)

For example:

Whenever I see a column with a true value I need to produce different file of it including the row with the value of true.

So the output should be like this:
[output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8xKJ.png)

[output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFugb.png)
[output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ceMT.png)

Thanks in advance guys, hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this :

tFileInputExcel -> main -> tReplicate -> main -> tFilterRow (quoteName equals quote1
) -> tlog

```
                                   -> main -> tFilterRow (quoteName equals 
                                   quote2 
                                             ) -> tlog 
                                  -> main -> tFilterRow (quoteName equals quote3 
                                             ) -> tlog 
                                  -> main -> tFilterRow (quoteName equals quote4 
                                             ) -> tlog
```

Or using a `tMap` component
would do the staff using filtering optin in the output

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dynamic solution.
Your input file should be sorted on "quoteName"

[image]

1. tFileInput : read your file
2. tFilterRow : filter on isLastItem : only "true" value (so you'll get only one row for each quoteName)
3. tflowToIterate : convert your flow into an iteration : you'll have n iterations created (n being the number of distinct quoteNames).
4. tFileInput : re-read your entire file in your current Iteration
5. tFilterRow : filter on quote=((String)globalMap.get("row2.quote"))  (with row2.quote being the value of your globalVariable created by tFlowToIterate)
6. tFileOutput : output file. You can put something like : "C:/Temp/"+((String)globalMap.get("row3.quote"))+".txt" in order to generate your distinct files.

Use "Outline" view to get access to global variables created by tFlowToIterate.